# Hadoop line numbers

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Is there an input format that will supply line numbers to the mappers? I need to get all the file + line occurrences of a given set of words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this thread with the different options.

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/current-line-number-as-key-td2958080.html

Comment: Why don't you share the code to the Apache project? It might be useful to others also.

Comment: As for 2021 the link is not available